# REST API - how to deal with post and functional errors

Tags: java, rest

I have a REST service which is a POST to create a user, if the user does not exist, the user is created, and the service returns a 200 with the user in a json format.

Case 1: What if the user exists already, do I return a functionnal exception, so a json containing an error (all of this managed by the error handling of spring boot), and what about the http status code
Some people say to send a 303 or a 409 ... many different answers, and what about the response body in that case?

Case 2: What if in the backend we have let say a rule on the name (like containing a space) which returns an error (space not allowed in a name), same questions, do i have to return a functionnal exception and what about the http status code in this case

Somehow I want the API consumer to know what kind of json structure to handle and  i guess the http status code helps for that ?

Comment: https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/rest-api-response-codes/

Comment: What are the business rules if you create a user that already exists?  Is it an error if it's attempted?  Is it ok?  Does the caller need to know if there is a duplicate?  Answer the business requirements first and then map that to a response code and response body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on how one interprets the various http status codes and how user friendly do you want your HTTP payload responses to be. Below are few suggestions:

**NEW USER CREATED** : If its a new user and gets created successfully in the backend then you return http status code 201. This is a technical status code. You can also return a functional status in the response body mentioning *"User created"*
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/201

**USER ALREADY EXISTS** : If the user already exists, you should respond with http status code 200 with a response payload body mentioning a functional status  *"User already exists"*

**USER CREATION FAILED** : If the new user rules are not satisfied at the backend service and it throws an error then the http status code of 400 can be used and functional status in response payload of *"User creation failed, please conform to the user name rules"* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400

For an API Consumer to know everything about your API's, you may want to provide a API specification document. You may use open API spec(previously known as swagger) https://swagger.io/specification/

Answer (score 1):

> Somehow I want the API consumer to know what kind of json structure to handle and i guess the http status code helps for that ?

Not quite.

The HTTP status code is meta data in the [transfer documents over a network](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=3m08s) domain.  It communicates the overall semantics of the response (for instance, is the body of the message a representation of a resource, or a representation of an error? is this response cachable? and so on).

For unsafe requests in particular, [cache invalidation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.4) is sensitive to "non-error status codes".  The difference between 303 (non-error status code) and 409 (error status code) can be significant.

The Content-Type header gives you a mechanism to describe the kind (schema) of the message you are returning (ex: [application/problem+json](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7807)).

---

The way I think about it: the information for your bespoke consumer belongs in the message-body; we lift data from the message-body to the HTTP metadata so that general-purpose components can take advantage of that information (for example, by invalidating cache entries).

So we would normally start by defining the schema and semantics of the message body, and making sure that we have intelligent ways to communicate all of the things we want the caller to know.  In other words, we are defining the documents that we pass to the client, and how to extract information from them.

Information that HTTP components need to know get copied from our bespoke document into the standardized forms (status code, headers).

---

Where things get complicated: the fact that something is an "error" in your domain, that doesn't necessarily mean that it should also be considered to be an "error" in the transfer of documents over a network domain.

A common case: we are using our API to navigate some work through a process; that process has a happy path, and also some exceptional paths that we normally try to avoid (accounts are overdrawn, items are out of stock, etc).

An HTTP request can move work from the happy path to an exception path *and still be a "success" in the transfer of documents domain*.

The easiest heuristic I know is to think about previously cached copies of responses by the same target URI.  If those responses are still re-usable, then you are probably looking at a 4xx status code.  If the responses should be invalidated, then you are probably looking at a 2xx or 3xx status code.